# html viewer error

Tags: c#

I created an html code viewer.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace testa5ermra
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = UrltextBox.Text;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream());
            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

it works fine for all web pages except one page
that page is (http://www.sharecash.org)
can anybody tell me what is the different between this page and other pages
and can any body give me a code that can get html code for this page
I really searched every where and every answer would be appreciated

Comment: Is it bad that I'm tempted to believe that all this is is simply a subtle advertisement?

Comment: @Andy, I thought the same thing.

Comment: man it's not advertisement its an upload site am not posting my rreferal link here try it your self if you can get html for this page

Comment: I guess the question is kind of vague.  What error are you getting? Are you getting it from the stream or the rich text box? What rich text box are you using?

Comment: C:\del is not recognized as an inter............

Comment: Have you tried using an user-agent like _Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b11) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b11_

Comment: @Cyberdrew  here is the error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The operation has timed out      and i am trying to get the html source in the rich textbox

Comment: I've tried your code and this is odd. The code never gets to `response.GetResponseStream()` when loading _http://www.sharecash.org_

Comment: @Metod Hacker Medja  do u have a tutorial for that

Comment: For what? Adding an user-agent? Just add `((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";` after `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);`

Answer (score 0):

Download something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and monitor the HTTP messages going back and forth when you `HttpWebRequest` that site.

**EDIT**:  And then post what you see in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

@ sugerman here

```
> Request Count:    1
Bytes Sent:     429 (headers:429; body:0)
Bytes Received: 6,853   (headers:438; body:6415)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    01:56:31.020
ClientBeginRequest: 01:56:31.027
ClientDoneRequest:  01:56:31.027
Gateway Determination:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     200ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    01:56:31.228
FiddlerBeginRequest:    01:56:31.228
ServerGotRequest:   01:56:31.242
ServerBeginResponse:    01:56:33.800
ServerDoneResponse: 01:56:33.800
ClientBeginResponse:    01:56:33.800
ClientDoneResponse: 01:56:33.801

    Overall Elapsed:    00:00:02.7741587

RESPONSE CODES
--------------
HTTP/200:   1

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
text/html:  6,415
~headers~:  438

ESTIMATED WORLDWIDE PERFORMANCE
--------------
The following are VERY rough estimates of download times when hitting servers based in WA, USA.


US West Coast (Modem - 6KB/sec)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.10s
Elapsed Time:    1.10s


Japan / Northern Europe (Modem)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.15s
Elapsed Time:    1.15s


China (Modem)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.45s
Elapsed Time:    1.45s


US West Coast (DSL - 30KB/sec)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.10s
Elapsed Time:    0.10s


Japan / Northern Europe (DSL)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.15s
Elapsed Time:    0.15s


China (DSL)
---------------
Round trip cost: 0.45s
Elapsed Time:    0.45s
```